# Python - binary search - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary-search, index-error

I'm learning Python programm (I'm totally beginner) and I have a little problem in my programm for binary search.
This is my code:

```
import random

def binary_search():
    numbers = []
    for x in range(1, 100):
        y = random.randint(1, 100)
        numbers.append(y)
        numbers.sort()

    start_index = numbers[0]
    end_index = numbers[-1]
    mid_index = numbers[(end_index+start_index)//2]

    user_choice = int(input("Is it your number: " + str(int(numbers[mid_index])) + "? \n0 - your number is lower,\n1 - it's your number,\n2 - your number is higher: "))
    times = 0

    while user_choice != 1:
        times += 1
        if user_choice == 0:
            end_index = mid_index-1
            numbers = numbers[start_index:end_index]
        elif user_choice == 2:
            start_index = mid_index+1
            numbers = numbers[start_index:end_index]

        mid_index = (end_index+start_index)//2
        user_choice = int(input("Is it your number: " + str(int(numbers[mid_index])) + "? \n0 - your number is lower,\n1 - it's your number,\n2 - your number is higher: "))

    print("Oh, that was hard... but it took only " + str(times) + " times to guess your number!")
```

If the value of user_choice == 2, Python give me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\IT\python\ćwiczenia\practice python\binary search v.2.py", line 38, in <module>
        binary_search()
    File "C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\IT\python\ćwiczenia\practice python\binary search v.2.py", line 30, in binary_search
        user_choice = int(input("Is it your number: " + str(int(numbers[mid_index])) + "? \n0 - your number is lower,\n1 - it's your number,\n2 - your number is higher: "))
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea, why doesn't work, because for the value of user_choice == 0 or 1 works well. I can't see, where is wrong.

(Maybe I'm just a stupid girl who doesn't understand how it works and how it should work well.)

Thank you for helping me. Have a nice day and enjoy your coffee (or tea or whatever you drink) :)

Comment: I don't understand why you need random numbers? Why not just all numbers between 0 and 100? What is the purpose of random here? With random numbers you risk that the number the user has in mind is not in your list...

Comment: Hint: there is a problem in how you calculate `mid_index`. Keep in mind that the index is independent of the numbers in the array. The index is calculated in function of the **length** of `numbers`, not its content. (And I agree with @trincot, having a random array of numbers makes it tricky to guess numbers that actually are in the list)

Comment: @trincot I didn't think about it

Comment: @user2246849 Thank you for a tip. I need to learn more about this

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- The issue that is causing the error you get: your code slices the `numbers` list, but when the slice is taken at the right side, the `*_index` variables point to the wrong indices now. What previously was at index `mid_index + 1` now is at index 0, so some or all of those variables refer to indices that are out of range. The solution is to **not** slice your list. The changing `index` variables do all that is needed.
- `start_index = numbers[0]` does not assign the *index*, but the value at that index. It should just be `start_index = 0`. The same mistake is made for `end_index`, and `mid_index`.
- Picking random numbers may lead to gaps in your list, and it may be that the user chooses a value that does not occur in your list. The code should just create a list with every possible value that the user is allowed to choose, without any randomness.

Not a problem, but:

- `int(numbers[mid_index])`: it is not needed to call `int`, as `numbers` is already a list of `int` values.
- Maybe verify that `user_choice` is 0, 1 or 2, and otherwise print some message.
- Maybe show a message when the user says "less" but there is no lesser value, or "greater" but there is no greater value.
- There is some code duplication, like the `input()` and the definition of `mid_index` are done both before the first iteration, and at the end of each iteration. Move that logic at the top of the loop's body, and use `break` to exit the loop.

Here is the modified code:

```
def binary_search():
    numbers = list(range(100))

    start_index = 0
    end_index = len(numbers) - 1

    times = 0
    while True:  # avoid code repetition, and break in middle of loop
        mid_index = (end_index+start_index)//2
    
        user_choice = int(input("Is this your number: " + str(numbers[mid_index]) + "?\n"
             + "0 - your number is lower,\n"
             + "1 - it's your number,\n"
             + "2 - your number is higher: "))
        times += 1
        if user_choice == 1:
            break
        if user_choice == 0 and mid_index > start_index:
            end_index = mid_index-1
        elif user_choice == 2 and mid_index < end_index:
            start_index = mid_index+1
        else:
            print("Invalid input")

    print("Oh, that was hard... but it took only " + str(times) 
        + " times to guess your number!")


binary_search()
```

Comment: Wow, it's much better and less complicated than what I tried before. That's really simple. Thank you so much.